# Does Skype support push notifications?

Tags: notifications

I never seem to get instant messages when Skype is closed.

Should I receive a notification of a new IM?

Edit: I just realized I don't even get Skype calls. I had it confused with Tango calls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. In Windows Phone 7.5 Skype does not support push notifications. More than this, like you said, as soon as you leave the app (even without closing it going back) it makes you offline.

It looks like something about how Skype works and an app can't run in background.

It will be solved in Windows Phone 8 with integrated VOIP apps in OS (Skype and 3rd apps).

Comment: How about Windows Phone 7.8? I just assumed I was always online and would receive messages like my friends on iOS and Android.

Comment: It seams like it will not be possible even in 7.8. But nobody can guarantee at this time.